# WSL2 Conda Environment Debugging Issue in PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, wsl-2

I am unable to debug my code in PyCharm using the conda environment in WSL2. I get an error message saying 'Failed to connect to Python debugger, Timeout waiting for response on 501'

I have turned off all the firewalls on Windows, but the connection still fails